# How to handle data fetching in multiple components in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native. Currently, I have multiple components, and each component does several fetches before rendering. The idea that I have  to make a loading screen while the app.js is rendering. But then, other components will still be loading when app.js is shown. What is the best way to do all the fetches in all components while loading the app. I have found about Higher Order Component and Redux. However, I don't know what is the best approach to use.

Comment: You want to show loading until all fetches are done? Please try to give us any simple code example

Comment: For example, each component has some get requests from APIs. The problem that i am facing is that it takes a while for each component to show because it is fetching. The solution is to implement a loading screen where all fetches are done and saved locally. But this will be a not a good way as I need to pass all the variables to other components.

Comment: That is why I am looking for something like Redux, Hooks, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that there are 3 main concepts and realizations for today that solve the issue you have.

- [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)
- [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html)
- GraphQL with all its clients [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/), [Relay](https://relay.dev/)

There is no Best or Correct way to handle the global state, just one you chose. One concept can be more familiar for you, other super-new.
I would recommend you to read the documentation and one you think is easier to work with  - is one you need.

Comment: What about Hooks?

Comment: @Chefk5 please, be more constructive in your feedback.